# React - require some aid with saving data to a table

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

I have a table with dynamically generated column headers and rows, a user can enter in data to the rows and when they click save the data should be saved into that row but at the moment it isn't saving the values to the table but it is saving them on my database. Ideally I would like it so that when the save button is clicked the data will be saved to the row and is then viewable in that row (if that makes any sense).

Here is the code I am working with (I know it is a mess at the moment!):

Code for data input form:

```
import React from 'react';
import AppStore from '../../stores/AppStore';

export default class RowForm extends React.Component {
    state = {dataEntries: []};

    onChange = (event, element) => {
        let dataEntries = this.state.dataEntries;
        dataEntries[element] = event.target.value;
        this.setState({dataEntries});
    };

    editStop = () => {
        this.props.editStop();
    };

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        let access_token = AppStore.getToken();
        let id = AppStore.getTable().id;
        let dataEntries = this.state.dataEntries;
        let dataEntriesArray = [];
        for (let key in dataEntries) {
            if (dataEntries.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                dataEntriesArray.push({contents: dataEntries[key]});
            }
        }

        this.props.handleSubmit(access_token, id, dataEntriesArray);

    };

    componentDidMount() {
        let nameArray = AppStore.getTable().columns.map((obj) => {
            return obj.name;
        });

        let dataEntries = nameArray.reduce((obj, name) => {
            obj[name] = null;
            return obj;
        }, {});
        this.setState({dataEntries});
    }

    render() {

        let {dataEntries} = this.state;

        return (
            <tr>
                {Object.keys(dataEntries).map((element) => {
                    return (
                        <td key={element}><input type="text" className="form-control" id={element} placeholder="enter data" value={dataEntries[element]} onChange={event => this.onChange(event, element)} /></td>
                    );
                })}
                <td>
                    <button className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.editStop}><i className="fa fa-ban"></i>Cancel</button>
                    <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.handleSubmit}><i className="fa fa-check"></i>Save</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
```

After the data has been entered and submitted (it is an array of objects like dataEntriesArray = [{contents: "value"}, {contents: "value"}, {contents: "value"}, {contents: "value"}].

And here is how I am rendering the table (this is where the problem is I think):

```
import React from 'react';
import TableHeader from './TableHeader.jsx';
import RowForm from './RowForm.jsx';
import {createRow} from '../../actions/DALIActions';
import AppStore from '../../stores/AppStore';

export default class Table extends React.Component {
    state = {rows: [], isNew: false, isEditing: false};

    handleAddRowClickEvent = () => {
        let rows = this.state.rows;
        rows.push({isNew: true});
        this.setState({rows: rows, isEditing: false});
    };

    handleEdit = (row) => {
        this.setState({isEditing: true});
    };

    editStop = () => {
        this.setState({isEditing: false});
    };

    handleSubmit = (access_token, id, dataEntriesArray) => {
        createRow(access_token, id, dataEntriesArray);
    };

    render() {

        let {rows, isNew, isEditing} = this.state;

        let headerArray = AppStore.getTable().columns;

        return (
            <div>
                <div className="row" id="table-row">
                    <table className="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <TableHeader />
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {rows.map((row, index) => this.state.isEditing ?
                                <RowForm formKey={index} key={index} editStop={this.editStop} handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit} /> :
                                <tr key={index}>
                                    {headerArray.map((element, index) => {
                                        return (
                                            <td key={index} id={element.id}></td>
                                        );
                                    })}
                                    <td>
                                        <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handleEdit.bind(this, row)}><i className="fa fa-pencil"></i>Edit</button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>)}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-xs-12 de-button">
                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.handleAddRowClickEvent}>Add Row</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I am using flux at the moment, and would ideally like to keep using it for now (I know about redux but I would ideally like to get it working in flux before I start refactoring my code). I suspect it is a problem with the way I am rendering my table.

Any help would be much appreciated, especially examples!

Thanks for you time!

Comment: Just looks like nothing is updating state when you hit save, its calling an action but does not actually update state, so, nothing changes, hence, nothing gets re-rendered. Doesnt look like you add any listeners for any store events to trigger a re-render either, unless you're rendering top down. I guess not which is why your UI does not update. If this is on the right track I'll rewrite as an answer.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking it was something like this but because I create the cells in each row by mapping through an array I am a bit stumped as to how I would tell the table to update with the correct values in each cell. Any thoughts?

Comment: The parent should contain all the table data, which is then passed through to children. When data changes it should change that top-level data structure, forcing a refresh and propagating that data through to the children again. In this case I assume the table data is already extracted and in the store? You could also remove the need for a save button by saving with each mutation to keep server and UI state in sync.

Comment: Yes but it is only stored after the form is submitted (the table inits with no rows and no data). The part I am struggling with is how to put the data into the correct cells as they are nested in various map functions and don't have identifiers, as to begin with they are empty cells with no value. Any thoughts on how I would do this? I need the save button as once a row is created, it can be edited and then saved again (which will update the state of the data).

Comment: You dont need the save button (although you might want it) as every mutation you make (change cell, add row etc etc) changes the underlying table data and then table data change can (and maybe should be, depending on your use-case) propagated to the server. In any case you want your UI _ask_ to update state in your store, the store then emits change events passing the table structure, parent component listens for that change event and re-renders using the table structure from the store. I'll write this up as an answer and we can probably delete this chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you probably want to extract your table data into your store, your UI child elements trigger change events, your store then updates its data and trigger change events which your parent component can listen for and update.

Something like the following simplified example, which mutates array elements:

```
class Store extends EventEmitter {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.data = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
  }

  onChange() {
    this.emit( 'update', this.data )
  }

  mutate( index, value ) {
    this.data[ index ] = value
    this.onChange()
  }
}

var store = new Store()

class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor( props ) {
    super( props )
  }

  // You probably want to use a dispatcher rather than directly accessing the store
  onClick = event => {
    store.mutate( this.props.index, this.props.value + 'Z' )
  }

  render() {
    return <button onClick={ this.onClick }>{ this.props.value }</button>
  }
}

class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor( props ) {
    super( props )

    // You probably want to be smarter about initially populating state
    this.state = {
      data: store.data
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    store.on( 'update', data => this.setState({ data: data }) )
  }

  render() {
    let cells = this.state.data.map( ( value, index ) => <ChildComponent index={ index } value={ value } /> )

    return (
      <div>
        { cells }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

For brevity child components here directly tell the store to change values, you'd probably want to dispatch messages/actions and have the store decide how to respond, the key is simply that the store data is passed to the parent component, which updates its state and triggers a re-render.

The flow here is that essentially the UI is dumb, it simply renders the data that it gathers from the store and dispatches a message to tell the store to update/mutate when a user action is detected (in this case a button press but it sound like you'll need an input of some sort), when the data in the store changes it emits (or could use a dispatcher also) a change event which forces the UI to re-render the new state. As child components are re-rendered at this stage they are populated with the new data state, ensuring that your UI remains consistent.

Comment: Thanks for your help!